# UPBGE - setting a Rigid Body Joint to 'breakable' with Python?

Tags: constraints

I'm trying to create breakable RBJ constraints in-game. I can make a regular 'Generic 6DOF' just fine, I'm just not sure how to enable the 'use_breaking' tickbox from Python.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import bge
from bge import logic
from bge import constraints
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
obj = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects
own = cont.owner
near = cont.sensors['Near']
constraint_type = 2

objects = logic.getCurrentScene().objects

edge_position_x = 0
edge_position_y = 0
edge_position_z = 0

edge_angle_x = 0
edge_angle_y = 0
edge_angle_z = 0

for i in near.hitObjectList:
    object_1 = own
    object_2 = i
    physics_id_1 = object_1.getPhysicsId()
    physics_id_2 = object_2.getPhysicsId()
    constraints.createConstraint(physics_id_1, physics_id_2,
                                constraint_type,
                                edge_position_x, edge_position_y, 
                                edge_position_z,
                                edge_angle_x, edge_angle_y, edge_angle_z)

    #breakable = True ??????
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey everyone! I still need some help on this, so feel free to reply if you happen to have any insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it

https://shuvit.org/python_api/bge.types.KX_ConstraintWrapper.html#KX_ConstraintWrapper.breakingThreshold

you create the constraint -> set the breaking threshold

```
constraint = constraints.createConstraint(#args)
force = 10
constraint.breakingThreshold = force
```

etc